# Looking for authentic-looking command-line work and source code

Tags: java, unix

This might sound strange, but, I'm working on an amateur film project that revolves around a coder/hacker. In a bid to add some authenticity to certain shots, I was wondering if anyone could help me with two things:-

1. Interesting source code files, preferably from an open-source project, revolving around networking or something similar that could appear in a source code editor on screen. And;
2. Insights into a few executable command-line functions that can run on repeat and make it appear that things are happening. A friend already gave me 'trace route' which is perfect, but very rudimentary, I was wondering if there are more.

I work on a Mac, and I have enough knowledge in this area to run some Java in the Terminal.app; but that's as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: 2) Run a java program that contains n number of print statements / ASCII stuff etc in n number of loops.

Comment: Never heard of a requirement that says "The program should pretend doing things and make this pretending visible in a command line." before... Interesting, but unfortunately off-topic here.

Comment: You could grab some source from an open source network project: e.g.: https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy/blob/1792facf4799347b9ae841bd577917f4b0296fd7/src/main/java/org/littleshoot/proxy/impl/ProxyConnection.java. Something like that.